# is it possible to make a TWRequest without using credentials saved in ACAccount?

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter

I would like to upload an image to Twitter directly using their new link `upload_with_media.json`.
Let me know if anyone is doing this using OAuth (currently I am using `DMTwitterOauth`).
Or is there a solution for making a `TWRequest` without using credentials saved in `ACAccount`? I have my application with key, secret key etc., but I don't want to save the credentials in a Twitter account under Settings.app.